# Google Search Appliance styling

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm working in a front end for the GSA, but I can't see how to style it.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use classes or the styling should be done inline on html tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either inline the CSS in the XSLT or host it on another webserver and reference it from within the XSLT as you would a normal HTML document.

Assuming you're outputting HTML from your XSLT then once you sort out where to put the CSS you just style it like any other HTML document.